# Facebook notification issue

Tags: android, facebook

I am create an application which send the notification itself who login with the app. Notifications are showing in notification tab when i open facebook in web browser.But notification are not showing in facebook native android app which is install in our device.

Can any one please help me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications. **Notifications are only surfaced on the desktop version of Facebook.com.**

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications